# Using SetWindowLong to override WndProc

Tags: java, windows-ce, jna

I need to set a WindowLong to override WndProc, I'm using this methods from coredll.dll:

```css
public interface CoreDll extends StdCallLibrary {
 //loads the coredll with unicode options
    CoreDll INSTANCE = (CoreDll)Native.loadLibrary("coredll", CoreDll.class,
                                                   W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);
    //native calls
    HMODULE GetModuleHandle(String lpModuleName);
    long GetWindowLong(HWND hwnd, int gwlWndproc);
    long SetWindowLong(HWND hWnd,int nIndex,Callback dwNewLong);
    LRESULT DefWindowProc(HWND hWnd, int uMsg, WPARAM uParam,LPARAM lParam);
  }
```

The original method signature in coredll is:

```css
LONG SetWindowLong( 
  HWND hWnd, 
  int nIndex, 
  LONG dwNewLong
);
```

But when I'm using it it always return 0, according to Microsoft "The previous value of the specified 32-bit integer indicates success. Zero indicates failure". Anyway, I'm trying to execute it this way:

```css
public interface CallbackProc extends Callback, StdCall {
 LRESULT callback(HWND hWnd, int uMsg, WPARAM uParam, LPARAM lParam);
}

//Get a handle to the current process
final HWND mainHwnd = CoreDll.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);

//Get a reference to the current process to send it in the new WndProc
long value=CoreDll.INSTANCE.GetWindowLong(new HWND(mainHwnd.getPointer()), -4);
final LONG_PTR prevWndProc = new LONG_PTR(value); 

//Sets the new Method to override WndProc
final RfidCallbackProc ptr=new RfidCallbackProc() {
 @Override
    public LRESULT callback(HWND hWnd, int uMsg, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) {
        //returns the call to the process  
        return CoreDll.INSTANCE.CallWindowProc(prevWndProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
};

//Sets the new method to override Windows' WndProc
int num=(int)CoreDll.INSTANCE.SetWindowLong(new HWND(mainHwnd.getPointer()),-4 ,ptr);
//NUM IS ALWAYS 0
```

If someone can give me a hint i will really appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are retrieving the module handle (GetModuleHandle), this handle reference an executable file (exe or dll) loaded into a process space, not a window. SetWindowsLong fails because the object you passed to it is not a window.
IIRC you have a method on forms/controls to get the native HWND, this is the right kind of object that you should pass to SetWindowLong.
Looking at the code I suppose that you have a RFID library that sends codes via windows messages. You may consider to wrap this with some native code into an object that then generates "regular" .NET events. It would be a bit more complicated but avoids some of the headaches that SetWindowLong may generate (ex: if the object with the wndproc is destroyed when the window is still valid).

Comment: Exactly I'm writing this to read codes sent via window messages, but I'm having a hard time with this, I've followed this code and finally I got the right SetWindowLong [link](https://github.com/pke/clipboard.monitor/blob/master/clipboard.monitor.windows/src/clipboard/monitor/windows/AbstractWindowsClipboardMonitor.java) but anyway I can't read the messages that the dll is sending. I'm able to read only 1 message within the PeekMessage loop then i try to call TranslateMessage(msg); DispatchMessage(msg); but it's not calling the WndProc i've defined

Comment: if you can take a look here I will really appreciate it, I've posted a new question with my new code [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487457/java-jna-read-codes-sent-via-window-messages)

Answer (score 1):

You need to obtain the right `HWND` value to pass to `GetWindowLong()`. If it's a Java window, you can use `Native.getWindowHandle()` on it.  Otherwise, you'll have to figure out some way of obtaining the `HWND` for the window you're targeting.

Once you have that, you need to pass in your callback object as the `dwNewLong` parameter.  You should define a new mapping for `SetWindowLong()` where the third parameter has the same type as your callback.

You should also avoid using Java `long`.  That's a 64-bit value, and should be used *only* when you're certain the corresponding native variable is also 64-bit.  Use `int` for 32-bit, and `NativeLong` when the native type is `[unsigned] long` (or `LONG` for w32).